# Maven build failure: couldnot parse error message: method: format

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to build my java project with Maven, however, I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   symbol:   method     format(String,int,int)
[ERROR] location: class String
```

Basically it complaining that String.format method is not found I guess

```
String.format(pathTemplate, useD8 ? 8 : 40, transactionFileNumber)
```

The compilation works fine on OS X and CentOS but it failed with this error on Ubuntu. Here is "mvn compile -v"

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-61-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Any clue how I can fix this on Ubuntu 14.04? Thanks a lot.

-----------------------Edit--------------------------
Output for mvn build -X

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project sales: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/junchao/Desktop/repos/Cassandra-benchmarking/app/src/main/java/cs4224/ClientApp.java:[48,35] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   symbol:   method format(String,int,int)
[ERROR] location: class String
[ERROR] /home/junchao/Desktop/repos/Cassandra-benchmarking/app/src/main/java/cs4224/ClientApp.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] System.err.println(String.format("Type %d: Total Transactions: %d", i, transactionCounts[i]));
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   symbol:   method format(String,int,int)
[ERROR] location: class String
[ERROR] /home/junchao/Desktop/repos/Cassandra-benchmarking/app/src/main/java/cs4224/ClientApp.java:172: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] System.err.println(String.format("Type %d: Time used: %f s", i, duration));
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   symbol:   method format(String,int,float)
[ERROR] location: class String
[ERROR] /home/junchao/Desktop/repos/Cassandra-benchmarking/app/src/main/java/cs4224/ClientApp.java:173: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] System.err.println(String.format("Type %d: Throughput: %f", i, throughput));
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   symbol:   method format(String,int,float)
[ERROR] location: class String
[ERROR] /home/junchao/Desktop/repos/Cassandra-benchmarking/app/src/main/java/cs4224/ClientApp.java:176: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] System.err.println(String.format("Overall: Total Transactions: %d", totalCounts));
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   symbol:   method format(String,int)
[ERROR] location: class String
[ERROR] /home/junchao/Desktop/repos/Cassandra-benchmarking/app/src/main/java/cs4224/ClientApp.java:177: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] System.err.println(String.format("Overall: Time used: %f s", totalTiming));
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   symbol:   method format(String,float)
[ERROR] location: class String
[ERROR] /home/junchao/Desktop/repos/Cassandra-benchmarking/app/src/main/java/cs4224/ClientApp.java:178: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] System.err.println(String.format("Overall: Throughput: %f", throughput));
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project sales: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

Output for javap java.lang.String | grep format

```
public static java.lang.String format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static java.lang.String format(java.util.Locale, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
```

Comment: can you pelase do mvn with `-X` and check the output ?

Comment: Where you do you get the message? From the compiler-plugin ? Have you configured to set the source/target to java 7/8 ?

Comment: I suggest you check which is the exact API of java.lang.String in your openJdk distribution: Simply open a shell and execute `javap java.lang.String`. Then look for the format(String,Object...) in the produced output.